# Same SKU in different app (Google Play)

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing

I have some application which use the same database to administer the in-app purchases, so one user could access to the same purchased item thru different apps. 
Is it possible to have the same SKU-name for two different application or should it be unique?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have same SKU-name for two different applications.

[image]

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1072599?hl=en

Comment: So do you think is it possible to manage those like i wrote above? :)

Comment: I think it is possible.. But I am not sure. Give a try :)